# How to get the output in relative units instead px by modifying this jQuery plugin of making custom style dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

**Scenario**

I'm making a Responsive website where I need to give multiple sizes to dropdown for various screen sizes with custom styling

**What I tried**

i'm using this  [DropKick plugin](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/plugin) to make custom styled dropdowns it adding width in `px`. it's very good for me

this is example I made using the plugin http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/HtW8C/1/

**Problem**

I want to increase or decrease the width and height of dropdown by increasing or decreasing the size of font inside dropdown but when i increase the `font-size`, dropdown doesn't scale accordingly

Link of plugin https://raw.github.com/JamieLottering/DropKick/master/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js

**Edit:**

I changed px to em here https://github.com/JamieLottering/DropKick/blob/master/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js#L117

But this plugin adds a inline width which i don't want. I want to control width by CSS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation in which the CSS `!important` rule is actually useful and a valid solution:

`a.dk_toggle { width: auto !important; }`

This will let you change the font size and have it expand automatically. Or, you can set an explicit width of your choosing, as long as you use that `!important` rule.

Comment: will !important override the inline style?

Comment: Yup, it will override even inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

What about when you need to target multiple dropdowns on a page with different widths?

[How to individually target multiple dropdowns in CSS for Dropkick Plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769888/how-to-individually-target-multiple-dropdowns-in-css-for-dropkick-plug-in)